# Unexpected error in Sinatra

Tags: hash, sinatra, ruby-1.9.2

In sinatra, I am executing this piece of Code containing values in Hash object:

```
@posts[0]["attachment"]["media"][0]["href"] # where @posts belongs to Koala::Facebook::API::GraphCollection class
```

works fine in sinatra application, however, the use of a loop:

```
@posts.each do |post|
      post["attachment"]["media"][0]["href"]
end
```

raises the following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The error that it displays when executed on command line is :

```
> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass     from
> (irb):12:in `block in irb_binding'    from (irb):11:in `each'     from
> (irb):11
```

What am I missing?

Comment: not all posts have attachments?

Comment: @Slartibartfast Thanks a ton for helping me out.. Just a silly mistake caused me to uninstall my ruby and use different versions of ruby using rvm(but it was good to start using RVM) and search various forums... Thanks again!!!